# htaccess rewrite query on homepage URL problem

Tags: .htaccess

I want to make a RewriteRule rule so when someone goes to the base index of my site eg:

```
example.com/
```

I want this to happen:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/ /index.php?pageID=1
```

So when someone goes to the homepage; a query for pageID=1 is sent.

However the above code doesn't work, going to the homepage with the above code doesn't get the query sent. (other rewrite rules are working correctly)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember `RewriteRule` has no `/` at the beginning of it!

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?pageID=1
```

Comment: @Ezra and result? remember rewriterule has no / in beginning of it!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?pageID=1
```